# How to remove dynamically created controls

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am able to create controls dynamically, once the job is over I need to remove those and add new ones. But have no idea how to remove from the content panel.

I have used the following code to add a textbox:

```
TextBlock Tb= new TextBlock();
tb.Text = "Hello";
ContentPanel.Children.Add(Tb);
```

Comment: have you used invalidate on textblock ?

Answer (score 2):

In WPF the `Children` property is an [`UIElementCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection.aspx) and has `Clear()` and `Remove()` methods.  I assume it's the same on the Phone.

Answer (score 0):

```
ContentPanel.Children.Remove(tb);
```

This code will remove the `UIElement`. Or otherwise you can generate the `UIElement` collection and based on that you can remove that element.